# Need to remove rfh header before sending message to mq

Tags: ibm-mq, mq, rfh2

I'm using JndiDestinationResolver (JNDI-lookup) to resolve destination which i have added on application server.I saw solutions to remove rfh from message is by appending--> queue + "?targetClient=1". I'm passing jndi-name to send(Destination,meassage) and need help to understand how i can set this variable (context file or on app server).
One solution mention- On the administered object there is a property called TARGCLIENT which should be set to 'MQ'.How and where exactly we need to set this on WAS.
I really appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Comment: What version of WAS?

Comment: WAS version is 8.0

Comment: I don't have a screen shot to provide but when you define the JNDI for the queue itself there is a option that should have values of either MQ or JMS.  Look at this link for more info: ["Target client" field is not displayed in the WebSphere Application Server Administration Console V7, V8.0 and V8.5 (RFH Header)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21421492)

Comment: Thanks so much its really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is no longer necessary to change the message producer to do this now, there are other options.

So long as your queue manager is at MQ V7.0 or above, you can alter the queue definition on the queue manager as follows, and the RFH2 header will be removed before the message is given to the consumer.

```
ALTER QLOCAL(q-name) PROPCTL(NONE)
```